# AADB2C Cost for Password Reset

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to understand how to estimate (cost) Password change / reset functionality in AAD B2C.

Can someone help me on this? Are these based again on Authentication?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have a sure answer for this, but I'm guessing the reset would count as an authentication. There is no built-in password change functionality btw.

Comment: When we reset a password, an email is sent and then we have to verify the code and then the password is reset. There are multiple steps. So from Authentication count it might be just one token generation. So would that mean for every Password reset we have to then consider one Authentication?

Comment: I would think each token generation would count as an authentication.